# Where does routes fit in mvc architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I am new to programming so sorry if this question sounds stupid

I was reading about MVC framework from [turtorial point](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvc_framework/mvc_framework_introduction.htm)

From the blog post, I was able to understand that in MVC

M -> Model

Model is responsible for handling data required b/w controller and View. This would probably be getting data from Database?

V -> View

Everything user see/interact -> Primarily frontend?

C- Controller

Handles incoming request, get params or body, transforms the request and sends it o the Model. Model will give back the data and send it to controller. Controller can then process/manipulate the data and send it to View?

From my above understanding, I thought to routes and controller are the same. I started with Ruby on rails and I saw folder config containing routes.rb.

Can someone confirm if my above understanding is correct and if yes, Can you think of any particular reason that ruby on rails code would have a folder config containing routes.rb file?

Answer (score 3):

Your understanding of Models, Views and Controllers seems fine; everything you said is correct.

> From my above understanding, I thought to routes and controller are the same.

The routes file exists to determine *how to handle the URL*.

Suppose StackOverflow were build on rails, and you wanted the path for this question (`/questions/63884488/where-does-routes-fit-in-mvc-architecture`) to point to `QuestionsController#show`.

Somehow, your rails application needs to know what to do with paths in the format: `/questions/<question_id>/*`. That's the job of the route, not the controller; the controller has no knowledge of which path format(s) it responds to.

You could have multiple different path structures point to the same controller action, or you could have one path structure *conditionally* point to multiple controller actions.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of Model, Views and Controller is spot on. Routes acts as a middleman in the MVC architecture. Let me use an example to explain this:

Lets say an http request comes in, first thing it hits is routes.Routes is what determines: who do i need to send this request to? Routes is going to use the path and request body of the request to figure out where the request is to be sent.

Routes has a list of paths and methods that are associated with controllers.

Controllers are used to control resources, eg: a users controller will figure out how to process requests about users.

Hence it's the routes job to send user requests to the users controller and it's also the routes job to tell
the users controller what to do with the users request. That's what routes does.